# Docker, webpack and env variables

Tags: docker, webpack, kubernetes, environment-variables

I'm trying to compile some special environment variables into my JS like so:

```
const publicEnvVars = [  
    'GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY',
    'GOOGLE_DISTANCE_API_KEY',
    'SENTRY_PUBLIC_DSN',
    'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY',
    'RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY',
]

let webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(Object.fromEntries(publicEnvVars.map(v => [`process.env.${v}`, JSON.stringify(process.env[v])]))),
    ...
```

This was working great for development with webpack-development-server until I realized that my precompiled Docker image won't be able to pick up these environment variables.

I can't pass a .env file to `docker build`, so that's out of the question. Don't want to pass them one-by-one as `--build-arg`s either.

I can maybe try to inject some vars at runtime, but I don't think I really want to put all of these env vars in the HTML of every page in a `<script>` tag.

How else might I deal with this?

I'm also using Kubernetes if that helps.

Comment: Would this solve your problem: [k8s-define-environment-variable-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) ?

Comment: Do you want the variables at build time or runtime?

Comment: @HelloWorld No, I've defined the environment variables no problem, just trying to figure out the best way to get them into JS.

Comment: @JordanSimba I guess it doesn't matter. I like build time because webpack will prune whatever isn't used. Don't love baking them into my Docker image though.

Comment: A couple things. You can COPY the .env file into the image or any file and `source file_with_env_vars`. You can simply use the ENV directive in the dockerfile to declare env bars but without initialization these won't be available at build time. You can use the same ENV directive with default values which will be available at build time.